# How can I update multiple rows in one to many relation without using while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables **tblUser** and **tblActivityLog** in one to many relation.
Somehow down the line we screwed up some data and need to apply a patch to fix this now.

**tblUser** contains single row for each user while **tblActivityLog** has multiple rows for one user based on each action user takes. The datetime column in **tblUser** is varchar and in **tblActivityLog**, it is datetime. Now I need to update the last updated date from **tblActicityLog** to **tblUser**.

I know it's really silly that datetime was set as varchar but it was appropriate at that time.

I need to update **tblUser** with the datetime value of the latest row from **tblActivityLog**.

One of the ways would be to use while loop but I'm wondering if there are better ways to achieve this. I searched related questions but could not quite find something close to my issue. If you guys know related question within stackoverflow then please point me there or It would be great to get some inputs here as well.

I'm trying something like below:

**Schema:**

```
create table #tblUsers
(
    user_id int,
    datetime_updated varchar(50)
)

create table #tblActivityLog
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    user_id int,
    [datetime_updated] datetime
)
```

**Query:**

```
update #tblUsers u set datetime_updated = (select top 1 [datetime_updated] from  
   #tblActivityLog where user_id = u.user_id order by [datetime_updated] desc)
```

**EDIT:**

Using alias causes error, so one solution is to use query below:

```
update #tblUsers u set datetime_updated = (select top 1 [datetime_updated] from  
   #tblActivityLog where user_id = #tblUsers.user_id order by [datetime_updated] desc)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your query looks like it is already a set-based solution.  Dan Bracuk's answer is more efficient, but even so, as it stands, your query will not require a WHILE loop to update all records.

Comment: Well seems so   :)  Good catch !!!
Guess what was the issue? Using alias in the update table throws error. If I use the table name instead then it works. 
Here is that I tested in SQL Fiddle. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bcdd3/2

Comment: Cool, man. :)  That being said, I would still go with Dan's way.  You are essentially using a cursor-based solution by pulling a subquery for every row, as well as having overhead for sorting the get the TOP 1.  Dan's solution is fully set-based and I recommend it.

Comment: "it's really silly that datetime was set as varchar" - it's also silly to have a column that's dependent on values in a related table - would a view be possible?

Comment: @DStanley As a matter of fact yes. I'm trying to get rid of the log table and just want to updated the last updated time before I remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of construct will give you the general idea of what you want to do.  You can work out the details.

```
update tblUsers
set datetime_updated = convert(max_dt, etc)
from tblUsers join
(select user_id uid
, max(datetime_updated) max_dt
from tblActivityLog
group by user_id ) temp on user_id = uid
```

Comment: This surely one of the ways. Thank you very much. 
Your example also led me to think of creating temp table and using partition to get top rows and then use it in join within update statement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What about an update with a JOIN instead of a Subquery?

```
update U
set u.datetime_updated = Al.datetime_updated
FROM #tblUsers U
inner join #tblActivityLog Al on u.user_id = Al.user_id
```

Looks simpler to me :)

Comment: I thought of that but would it guarantee the latest one would be updated? Join can result in multiple rows.